# Why is JomDirectory extension appearing blank in localhost?

Tags: php, joomla, localhost

I bought this extension for Joomla called JomDirectory and I'm very happy with it. It works fine in Joomla, and it does what I was expecting it to do. The problem comes when I wanted to start personalising more my website than what I can do with Joomla Backend access. I want to work and develop locally, I already have downloaded Eclipse and my full site and configured pretty much everything (I hope). The whole site is accessible through localhost with any problem except the JomDirectory page. It appears completely blank and I can't see any error or message. When I try to inspect the source code it's also completely empty, without even the opening `<html>` tag. There's nothing.

Any clue what can this be?

Comment: In `System Configuration->Server ` set `Error Reporting` to `Maximum` so you can see more php details.

Comment: I can't login to the backend (locally) either... Everything else is working fine, even the connection to the database. But I can't login.. :(

Comment: Then try to set it via `configuration.php`. Set `$error_reporting = 'maximum';` Also check your `error-log` file.

Comment: thanks @mokiSRB! At least now I have some errors to check...

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching a bit more... What I found now is where the program stops: This is the file .../legacy.php. The line 211 is the one starting with $result. Never gets back, so never executes the `echo $result` and that's why I get a blank page, not a PHP error.

```
public function display($tpl = null)
{
    $result = $this->loadTemplate($tpl);
    if ($result instanceof Exception)
    {
        return $result;
    }

    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Can you copy the file with error once again from your server, I think you might be missing an open curly brace or something, which produces the parse error. Or check the file again to see If there is any logical error in the file.

Comment: It is exactly the same document. Checked it once again with version control.